# Get substring from url using Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following image src:

```
<img src="http://xyz.example.com/abc/def/ghi/someimagename.jpg">
```

How can I use jquery to extract the image name without the extension e.g. in the above case this would be `someimagename`?

Comment: I would recommend that you use this library: [link](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) it has what you need.

Comment: `"http://xyz.example.com/abc/def/ghi/someimagename.jpg".split('/').pop()`

Comment: How did you manage to ignore all suggestions of duplicates? Also string handling is not jQuery, just plain JS.

Comment: [`.split('/').pop().split('.').shift();`](http://jsfiddle.net/bjwxLw7r/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `/\/([^\/]+?)\.jpg">/` and get the capturing group value

```js
var str = '<img src="http://xyz.example.com/abc/def/ghi/someimagename.jpg">';
var res = str.match(/\/([^\/]+)\.jpg">/)[1];
document.write(res);
```

Comment: Why use lazy quantifier (`[^\/]+?` in `/\/([^\/]+?)\.jpg">/`) with a negated character class? The result is the same as with a greedy one.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this too.

```
var string = '<img src="http://xyz.example.com/abc/def/ghi/someimagename.jpg">';
string = string.split("ghi/")[1].split(".")[0];
```

EDIT:

or you can do the following, which will work pretty good for any kind of url

```
var string = '<img src="http://xyz.example.com/abc/def/ghi/someimagename.jpg">';
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

string = reverse(string).split(".")[1].split("/")[0];
string = reverse(string);
```

Comment: It does not have jpg extension, recheck please.
about URL you might be right